# How to undo accidentally committed 'Unversioned' Files in GIT

Tags: git, git-reset

In IntelliJ, unversioned files are highlighted red. I do *not* want them in my git repo ever. These may be temp `.java` files I'm working on in various packages.

However, last night I accidentally added hundred of unversioned files and committed them. I did not push them. All these red files now turned white :(

I tried to do a hard reset to my most recent pushed commit, let's say `20a482h`

I did `git reset --hard 20a482h` but the files are still white.

If I do `Git > Push`, it shows a list of 5 commits!! I went to reset my local files to the exact state they were in last night before this happened.

How do I make them all red again, and unversioned?

```
git status
On branch origin
Your branch is up to date with 'origin'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

       code/src/main/java/comm/UnwantedFile1.java
       code/src/main/java/comm/UnwantedFile2.java
       ..... 200 + files ....
```

However, there are plenty of "white" files that aren't listed above. I want them red again, simply in my local files but nowhere else.

**.gitignore**

```
*.iml
.idea
*.css
/app-layout-demo/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/demo/styles.scss.cache
/app-layout-addon/src/main/polymer/bower_components/
/app-layout-addon/src/main/polymer/build/
### Java template
# Compiled class file
*.class

# Log file
*.log

# BlueJ files
*.ctxt

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

For instance, given the package 'Help' below. The file `QuickTip.java` should not be white, it should be red. Right now it's versioned and will be included in any commit/push. The other 2 files in `Help` should stay versioned.

[image]

How do I unversion 200+ files in various packages?

Comment: Can you show the outputs of `git status` and the content of `.gitignore`?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my answer. By the way, I just did a hard reset HEAD~4 to reset the past 4 commits, which is why it says I'm up to date. If I do `Git>Push` in IntelliJ, it shows no commits. But many `.java` files are white, and I want them reverted to red like they were last night before my accidental commit of them.

Comment: So the git status does show that you modified the .gitignore. What's the change you did on that file? What if you reset that file to a "clean" state and try git status again?

Comment: I think that `.gitignore` change was caused by me deleting a `.java` file after the fact. I just removed the bottoms lines from `gitignore` so it's like it was last night. If I do `git status` it still says I'm up to date. Now my gitignore looks exactly like it does in my question.

Comment: I added a small image to my question to better explain my dilemma.

Comment: @Mathomatic could you also provide the output of `git status src/main/java/help/QuickTip.java`?

Comment: `git status src/main/java/help/QuickTip.java
On branch origin
Your branch is up to date with 'origin'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: Wait... I made a mistake. `QuickTip.java` should remain. I can't find any of the old red files anymore in my local files, even as white. Does this mean the hard reset to the `origin` must have properly removed them? I seem to only have local files that I want now! Weird

Comment: To clarify, there are still come red files remaining, but they weren't (for whatever reason) committed last night with the other unversioned files. It's only the previously red unversioned files that I commited last night that are now missing from my local files. Which is fine with me. I'm just confused how I got from A to B.

Comment: @Mathomatic yes, the hard reset removed the files that you committed. It wouldn't remove them if they weren't committed though.

Comment: Oh wow, so I effectively got rid of them very efficiently? By hard resetting to my pushed commit, it removed all local files that weren't in that pushed commit (unversioned files) and thus removed them upon reset. All the files I wanted to keep thus remain, since they existed in that pushed commit. Wow, I feel like a dodged a bullet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice would be to `.gitignore` the files.

They'll turn grey instead of red and stop bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `git log` to see how far away the commit you want to go back to is
2. Run `git reset HEAD^ --soft` Assuming its the last commit you want to reset, if you want to go back 2 commits you can do `HEAD^^` instead. This will reset your state to that commit but wont discard your changes thanks to the `--soft` flag, so now if you do `git status` you should be able to see these files again along with the other changes you made in these commits
3. `git add` the files you want ignoring the ones you dont and make a new commit
4. Reset/Delete/Ignore the remaining files by running `git reset --hard`, `git checkout .` and `git clean -f -d` to delete & reset the unwanted changes
5. `git push` your changes after you verify the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I had just solved it but I believe your point #4 is what I had to do effectively to reset my local files and delete the unversioned files. I think I'm good now. Thanks